# How can I delete everything before > symbol in DiscordJS

Tags: discord.js

How can I slice everything before > symbol in Discord JS Bot?

```
else if (command === 'dm') {


    
    if (mention == null) { return; }
    message.delete();
    mentionMessage = message.content.slice(">");
    mention.send(mentionMessage);
    message.channel.send("Done!");
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's quite hard to tell what you're trying to do but you can remove everything before ">" in a string by doing this.

```js
var test = "ONE TWO THREE > FOUR FIVE SIX";
var returnValue = test.split(">")[1].trim()

// returnValue = "FOUR FIVE SIX"
```

Comment: if it helped, press the green tick next to the answer so it helps others know!